# Remove a scroll on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website and I have a navbar that slides across from the right hand side, showing the menu etc. However when on mobile I can scroll my screen across and see part of the back ground for the navbar. I have tried the `overflow-x:hidden;`-approach on the body and html elements and that hasn't worked. I also tried various solutions mentioned in old posts on SO. Is there anything I could do?

Mobile view of website allows me to scroll to the right when it shouldn't allow it to happen. Here is my code:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');


  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
      }
    });

    //burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle-ani');
  });
}

window.onscroll = function(event) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

navSlide();
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #4A4F52;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <h4>House of elders</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="coc.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
      <li><a href="admins.html">Admin Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML and JS (if any).

Comment: added JS and HTML snippets

Comment: See [here](https://i.imgur.com/kHWSfeV.gifv). With the code you've posted above, I can't see a horizontal overflow. I see some other issues but that doesn't appear to one of them. I don't think I have all the code necessary to debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the Scrolling bar x and y in the page you can add this to your CSS script :

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; }
html { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Thats work in the Computer i don't if it works on the mobile too.

Comment: Still getting the same issue with this. I have attached a screenshot of what i am seeing.

Comment: you sed just the scrolling bar x hidden and you forget the y one.